# How do I test a function that is in a class with Jest

Tags: jestjs

I have a function that is in a class :

Simplified version :

```
export class Button {
  getAttributes(el) {

    //random code that was removed for simplicity

    return dataAttrs;
  }
}
```

I was wondering how do I test this in Jest.

Comment: Why not the following? 
`const button = new Button();
const result = button.getAttributes(el);
expect(result).toMatchSnapshot();`

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me :

```
test('get attributes on element', () => {
  let button= new Button();
  var element = document.createElement('a');
  element.setAttribute('href', 'https://www.google.ca/');
  element.innerHTML = 'Test';


  expect(breadcrumb.getAttributes(element)).toBe('Hello');


});
```

Answer (score 0):

if there is simple class like the one that u define u can do:

```
it('We can check the class constructor', () => {
  const classObject = new classObject();
  expect(classObject ).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

and use whatever the methods that Jest have.

But if there are complex classes and methods that ones are dependent from others i suggest you to read [this](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks) and you can automatize it or can do it manually, mock the dependences and test it out.